# Why the final output of the recursive function is 5?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, recursive-query, tail-recursion

Why the output of the above code is 5 as the function should go to first 5-4-3-2 (since no output) loop decrements to 1 so return 12 so at last 12+1..... so the answer must not be 5 i guess ?

```
using namespace std;
int  x()
{
}
int reee(int n)
{
  for(int i=n; i>0; i--)
  {
  if(i==2)
  {
    return x();
  }
  else if(n==1)
  {
    return 12;
  }
  else
  {
     return reee(i-1)+1;
  }
}
}
int main()
{
  cout << reee(5) << " ";
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. Also, what is `return x();` supposed to do?

Comment: Wht is `x()` empty?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour since `x` does not return anything.

Comment: it will never get to n==1, because at i==2, x() is called, which is non-recursive.

Comment: Note that your loop always returns on the first iteration, so it will never loop.

Comment: I think you have a serious misunderstanding here `since no o/p`. `x` promises to return a value but doesn't. That means you program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: did you write this code? In any case I would suggest to start from scratch. It is not clear what it is supposed to do, but it is clear that it doesn't do that. This looks like a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: "_Why the final output of the recursive function is 5?_" - "_so the answer must not be 5 i guess ?_" - No that's not how this works. Add your debugging efforts into it. Where does it go wrong? Explain how you came up with this and what you expected it you return.

Comment: Please indent the code, it is unreadable, and that's how bugs are introduced.....

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a for loop in this case as your function is already a recursive function so it keeps running the function until it is 2. When it is 2, it returns x making it empty body + 3. If you want it to get to 1, in the if statement of i==2, you should make it return(i-1)
Therefore, your code should be like this:

```
using namespace std;

int reee(int n)
{
  if(n==2) {
    return reee(--n);
  } else if(n==1) {
    return (n+12);
  } else {
     return reee(--n)+1;
  }
}
int main()
{
  cout << reee(5) << " ";
}
```

That should help you with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually my doubt was not with the logic of the code. I  actually wanted to know why the output is 5 of my code. what is happening there?

Comment: Your for loop runs only once or doesn't even run at all, and since the variable i is set to n which is 5, it returns (5-1)+1 which will give you 5 at the end and that is why the output of your code is 5.

Comment: But for the first time lets suppose n=5 then it return ree(4) and then the recursion goes on.The recursion takes place here if I am not wrong !! so why the final output is 5

Answer (score 0):

```
int  x()
{
}
```

Calling this function results in Undefined Behavior because your function declared to return `int` doesn't return anything.

Crank up the compiler warning and while you are in learning stages treat warnings as errors.